# Каким является предложение "Я не понимаю, стоит ли мне это делать"?

Tags: пунктуация

Каким является предложение "Я не понимаю, стоит ли мне это делать" - сложносочиненным или сложноподчиненным. По школьным правилам, если я ничего не забываю, получается, что это сложносочиненное бессоюзное. Так ли это? А если у нас такая ситуация  - "Я не понимаю, кто за это ответствен и стоит ли мне это делать"? Ставим ли мы запятую перед "и"? Разве не являются эти два предложения однородными придаточными?

Answer (score 1):

Да, сложносочиненное бессоюзное. Запятую перед и не ставим, потому что (да) придаточные однородные. Наличие союза на постановку запятой не влияет.